# Sklearn incorrect support value (number of samples in each class) for classification report

Tags: scikit-learn

I am fitting an SVM to some data using sklearn. I have 24 samples in total (10 negative, 14 positive).

```
# Set model
clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'linear', C = 1)

# Create train, test splits and fit SVM to data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0, test_size = 0.3, stratify = y)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

I stratified by y to ensure I have an equal number of each class in my test set, which seems to have worked (see image below), however, the classification report says there are no negative samples:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for `classification_report` is `(y_true, y_pred, ...)`; you've reversed the inputs.

Here's one of the places where using explicit keyword arguments is a good practice.